# Vue.js - Child components are re-rendered while updating their position

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.draggable

I'm new to `Vue.js` and i'm using it alongside with `Vue-Draggable` in order to re-arrange the position of stand-alone widgets (components) inside the DOM.

I also want to be able to rearrange this position dynamically via an Ajax response containing the order.

The problem that i have with my current implementation is that when i'm re-arranging, the components are re-rendered. I don't want that.

Any ideas would be helpful.

```
<template>
  <draggable tag="div"
             class="container-fluid"
             @start="drag=true"
             @end="drag=false"
             handle=".v-drag-handle"
             v-bind="dragOptions"
             v-model="widgetList"
  >
    <transition-group type="transition">
      <component v-for="(widget, key) in widgetList"
                 :key="key"
                 :is="widget.widget">
      </component>
    </transition-group>
  </draggable>
</template>


 const widgets = [
    Component1,
    Component2,
    Component3,
    Component4,
    Component5
  ];

  export default {
    name: 'Stack overflow',

    data() {
      return {
        widgetList: [],
        drag: false,
        config: this.getHttpConfig(),
      };
    },

    computed: {
      dragOptions() {
        return {
          animation: 800,
          disabled: false,
          ghostClass: "v-ghost"
        };
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getWidgetOrder();
    },
    watch: {
      widgetList(val, oldVal) {
        if (oldVal) {
          this.setWidgetOrder(this.widgetList);
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      sort() {
        this.widgetList = widgets.map((widget, index) => {
          return { widget: widgets[index], order: index + 1 };
        });
      },
      getWidgetOrder() {
        this.prepareFormData('get');

        this.$http(this.config)
          .then(response => {
            //todo handle response
            this.sort();
          })
          .catch(response => {
            throw new Error('Could not get widget order.');
          });
      }
    },
    components: {
      Component1,
      Component2,
      Component3,
      Component4,
      Component5
    }
}
```

For time saving i have removed all non-related methods and i kept only the ones that are used while the problem is occurs.
 I believe that the problem is happening on the `v-model`, when the widgetList is updated i'm getting this issue.

Comment: You are re-assigning the `widgetList` object with every call of this `sort` method, only to update the `order` properties -- that could be the reason for the rerenders. You should just loop through it and update the individual `order` props when sorting.

Comment: In the original situation, I can not even see a key. I guess it was just null for all items, thus being useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here occurs because the `key` in the loop is changing, and Vue automatically re-creates the component.

The solution was to use the component's name as a key. `:key="widget.name"`

Comment: In my situation, I had found that the transition group was the actual culprit.